# ERROR: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

Here is what is going on in my OnCreate method. **the recycler view is defined within the class ( RecyclerView rvTweets;)**

```
 @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeline);

        client = TwitterApp.getRestClient(this);
        rvTweets = findViewById(R.id.rvTweets);
        tweets = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new TweetsAdapter(this, tweets);
        rvTweets.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rvTweets.setAdapter(adapter);



        populateHomeTimeline(); 
    }
```

There error says: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvScreenName"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivProfileImage">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProfileImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvScreenName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivProfileImage"
        tools:text="jesusislord" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBody"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvScreenName"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivProfileImage"
        tools:text="this is sample text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried adding maven(jitpack) to the all programs (in build:gradle project) and the raizlabs dependencies to my build:gradle app file

Comment: There is no RecyclerView defined in the layout file you posted

Comment: please share all code and error